# Gmail: Couldn't sign you in (automation)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, gmail, robotframework

When trying to login into gmail **Couldn't sign you in** error is displaying in automation

Scenario: I have a automation test case which performs login to gmail and read email content present in inbox.

From last one week this test case getting failed due to **Couldn't sign you in** error

Full error message:

```
You're using a browser that Google doesn't recognize or that's set up in a way we don't support.

To keep your Google Account secure, sign in on another browser or change your browser's settings. Learn more
```

Error page [link](https://accounts.google.com/signin/rejected?hl=en&rrk=46&rhlk=le)

Note: This work's in local machine but failing in AWS EC2 server

As per this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en) google restricts automation but for me its working in local machine!

Need help to resolve this!

Comment: The ec2 server is probably using a headless browser. That could be why it's not working. If you run it with a headless browser on your local machine, will it work?

Comment: Yes its working in headless and GUI modes of chrome

Comment: In local machine

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Steps:
 First Enter emailid using SendKeys, than Inside the Email text box SendKeys (Keys.Enter) rather than clicking next button.

Same goes for Password field.